# error 6 the handle is invalid writing to file on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Visual C++ 6 (not .NET) program on Windows (2008 R2) is returning an “Error code: 6, Error Detail: The handle is invalid” when trying to write to a file.  The file is created, but is blank because the error.

The Windows user account running the program is an Administrator on the machine. The error “just started happening” according to the user.

Again, file is created and appears to have correct permissions and ownership.  File is opened with fopen and written to with fwrite.

Why is the error occurring?
Does it have to do with group policy?
Where do I start to look?

---

[Updated 2015-01-28]

Code returning the error:

```
m_stream = fopen(m_sLogFile, m_sMode);

if ( m_stream == NULL )
{
    dwErrorCode = ::GetLastError();
    if (dwErrorCode != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS &&
        dwErrorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        CaptureError(this->FormatErrorCode (dwErrorCode));
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This is AFTER the file has been created...

```
hFile = CreateFile((LPCTSTR) sPathName,                                     // file name
    GENERIC_ALL,                                    // access mode
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,             // share mode
    NULL,                                               // SD
    CREATE_ALWAYS,                              // how to create                        
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | 
    FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,                          // file attributes
    NULL);                                              // handle to template file
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that your error handling code is broken.  Fwrite() does not generate a Windows error code, it generates an *errno*.

Comment: Please show the actual code that is failing.

Comment: Do you close the handle returned from `CreateFile` before you try the `fopen`?

Comment: Why are you mixing Windows API calls and CRT invocations anyway? This will not end well. You cannot reliably specify a share mode using `fopen` that is compatible with sharing permissions specified in your call to `CreateFile` in general. It is also not clear whether or not you are calling `CloseHandle` prior to `fopen`. Either way, you cannot expect the file to be immediately available after `CloseHandle` returns.

Comment: My question was voted down because the code was buggy/bad...not what I expected from a community.  To those who answered, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing `GetLastError`. You can only use it to get the error code of a Windows API function that failed (and only for those API functions which document that `GetLastError` can be used to get the error code). You can't reliably use it to get more information about a C standard library function that failed. Instead you need use the interface defined by the C standard, the `errno` variable mentioed by Hans Passant in his comment.

The reason why you can't use `GetLastError` here is because a C library function may need to make several Windows API function calls in order to implement the function. There's no guarantee that the last API called will generate a meaningful error code in the context of overall operation. It's also possible that no API gets called, if, for example, you exceeded the number of open files supported by the C runtime implementation.